# How to make Image clickable with URL once pulled from Blob

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I have a working code that pulls image blobs from the MYSQL database, However I want to in addtion make them click able so people can click to a product page. This is my working code so far I just haven't been able to add a Url to make the image clickable.  How would I do this?

```
<?php
    $id ='1';
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","brianrob_usr","","brianrob_productdb"); //keep your db name
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id = $id";
    $sth = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = $sth->fetch_array()){
    echo '<div><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/></div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an anchor tag  around the image.

```
echo '<div><a href="'.$row['URL'].'"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/></a></div>';
```

should do the trick presuming you have the URL as a column in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<div><img href="someurl.com" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/></div>';
```

Or, if it's dynamic and you have an image name in a field, do this:

```
echo '<div><img href="' . $row["imageName"] . '" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['Image'] ).'"/></div>';
```